# Create desktop shortcup with inno Setup with custon target

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I would like to create a desktop shortcup with inno Setup.
I don't know what i must add into the configuration file of inno Setup to create my custom target.

Here is the line that i want to use :

```
"%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\Application\chrome.exe" --app=file://%userprofile%/Desktop/web/index.html --disable-web-security
```

And here is the content of the script configuration file of inno Setup :

```
[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\SDK"; Filename: "{app}\index.html"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; IconFilename: {app}\tools\favicon.ico; Tasks: desktopicon
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to expect on user's computer side by side Chrome installation ? Don't you rather [`want to determine the Chrome executable`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22538486/960757) ?

Comment: It can be a second step, but for now, i would like to know how can i do to call chrome + link + extension flag

Comment: Ok thanks you. And, what can i do to be able to set the home directory of a user ?

Comment: Err, sorry, but which home directory ? Could you ask this separately, if possible ? If you mean working directory, then there is the `WorkingDir` parameter which you've already used...

Comment: In fact, i talked about the home directory of the user like : C:/Users/theUser

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, as far as I know, there is no constant for the user's profile folder root path (no constant that would return `%userprofile%` environment variable). There are [`constants`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm) for all necessary subfolders of user's profile root folder and so it's probably because no one usually needs to know that :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify icon parameters there's the [`Parameters`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=iconssection&anchor=Parameters) parameter available for [`[Icons]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=iconssection) section entries. The rest remains same as you already used. Just two notes; replace those environment variables by the corresponding path constants given by the Inno Setup scripting engine and be careful when using those variables when you're going to expand a file name with forward slashes (`file://%userprofile%/..`). Wouldn't such command line parameter fail in app. because it expands the path with baskslashes ?

In this script both mentioned issues should be considered:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\SDK"; Filename: "{localappdata}\Google\Chrome SxS\Application\chrome.exe"; Parameters: "{code:GetParameters}"

[Code]
function ForwardSlashes(const Value: string): string;
begin
  Result := Value;
  StringChangeEx(Result, '\', '/', True);
end;

function GetParameters(Value: string): string;
var
  S: string;
begin
  S := ForwardSlashes(ExpandConstant('file://{userdesktop}/web/index.html'));
  Result := Format('--app=%s --disable-web-security', [S]);
end;
```