# How to check if Google Chrome is installed on Windows machine using Inno Setup

Tags: google-chrome, inno-setup

I am developing an installer using Inno Setup and I need to find whether Google Chrome is installed in the machine.

I have found answers that say that I can check at the following path in the registry,

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome

But this didn't solve my problem. I don't have this path in my registry.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you checked [`this question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22467996/960757) ?

Comment: I checked the question now and had all my queries solved. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 6):

This will help:

```
(Get-Item (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe').'(Default)').VersionInfo
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way easier way to do this.

```
$chrometest = Test-Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe'

if($chrometest -eq $true){
   Write-Host "Chrome is installed"
}else{
   Write-Host "Chrome is not installed"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Know this is an old thread, however, building off of Walt's answer here is the full solution that I came up with:

```
$chromeInstalled = (Get-Item (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe').'(Default)').VersionInfo

if ($chromeInstalled.FileName -eq $null) {
Write-Host "Chrome is not installed"}
else {
Write-Host "chrome is installed"
}
```

Comment: Yes, You use the boolean value from previous answer.. How is this answer different from previous answer?

Comment: The only thing different is that the initial one was giving a starting point. What I ended up doing was expanding the answer to give a solution to what the original question was asking.

Comment: yea, write-host is not part of the question..  It's just a write out for you and your use case.. 

Your answer isn't different from the previous answer.